# GPIO over Raspberry Pi 3 model B using Node.js

Tags: node.js, gpio

I am trying to blink the led using raspberry pi 3 model B,

I have all the required modules installed on my machine i.e. npm , nodejs , pi-gpio (fixed the minor changes to detect the gpio )

Code is  :

```
var gpio = require("pi-gpio");

gpio.open(16, "output", function(err) {     
gpio.write(16, 1, function() {          
        gpio.close(16);                     
    });
});
//reading the data on the pin i.e pin : 16 
gpio.open(16, "output", function (err) {
    gpio.read(16, function (err, value) {
         console.log("Data is "+ value);
         gpio.close(16);
    });
});
```

But above code throws error while running it,

**node app.js**

error : 
**Error when trying to open pin 16
gpio-admin : could not flush data to /sys/class/gpio/export : Device or resource busy**

Thanks in advance

Any links where I can see the circuit diagram and code.

Concern : I dont want to change the platform i.e. node.js

pi-gpio which i am using is : https://github.com/rakeshpai/pi-gpio

Comment: Did you do the `sudo adduser $USER gpio` step? If you miss that you might not have permissions. If you did that did you log out and back in for your group change to take effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pi-gpio has already fixed the old and new sysPath (issue# https://github.com/rakeshpai/pi-gpio )

But it is dependent on quick2wire-gpio-admin lib.

**So small fix required in quick2wire-gpio-admin**

```
git clone https://github.com/quick2wire/quick2wire-gpio-admin.git
cd quick2wire-gpio-admin
```

The `src/gpio-admin.c` has

```
int size = snprintf(path, PATH_MAX, "/sys/devices/virtual/gpio/gpio%u/%s", pin, filename);
```

replace with :

```
int size = snprintf(path, PATH_MAX, GPIO_CLASS_PATH "gpio%u/%s", pin, filename);
```

Then go to `cd quick2wire-gpio-admin` directory

Then `sudo make uninstall` and

```
sudo make install
```

Then it is running fine.

The Code for is as follows : (filename : blinking12.js)

```
var gpio = require("pi-gpio");

var intervalId;
var durationId;
var gpioPin = 12;

gpio.open(gpioPin, "output", function (err) {

    var on =1 ;
    console.log("GPIO pin "+gpioPin+" is open toggling LED every 100mS for 10s");

    intervalId = setInterval( function () {
        gpio.write(gpioPin, on, function () {
            on = (on  + 1)% 2;
        }); 
    }, 100);
});

    durationId = setTimeout (function () {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        clearTimeout(durationId);
        console.log('10 seconds blinking completed');
        gpio.write(gpioPin, 0, function () {
            gpio.close(gpioPin);
        //process.exit(0);  
    }); 
}, 10000);
```

To run the code :

```
node blinking12.js
```

Output on my machine :

```
GPIO pin 12 is open toggling LED every 100mS for 10s
10 seconds blinking completed
```

Comment: This is the solution, at least for my self! :)

Answer (score 4):

`pi-gpio` is just writing to the GPIO device in the background so you can skip `node.js` and `pi-gpio` and do the same manually for testing purposes.

Example:

```
gpio.open(16, ...
# is the same as writing in terminal:
echo 16 > /sys/class/gpio/export
```

and

```
... "output" ...
# is the same as writing in terminal:
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/direction
```

etc.

First of all, try rebooting the Pi and see if that takes care of the issue.

If that didn't help, try manually closing/unexporting the pin as root and then re-run the script.

```
# unexport the pin as root in case something's holding on to it
sudo echo 16 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
```

The commands below basically constitute the `pi-gpio` API. These lines are what you would put in a shell script to control your GPIOs. Test them without sudo first in the order I've written them and if they don't work, try with sudo. If they still don't work, I think you have a wiring/hardware problem or need to change some system settings elsewhere.

```
# unexport the pin
sudo echo 16 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport

# export it again
sudo echo 16 > /sys/class/gpio/export

# make it an output
sudo echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/direction

# write a HIGH - is the LED on now?
sudo echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/value

# read the value of the pin - is it 1 after writing a 1 to the pin?
cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/value

# write a LOW - did it turn off?
sudo echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/value
```

Comment: "sudo echo 16 > /sys/class/gpio/export" seems to make a symbolic link "/sys/class/gpio/gpio16" instead of "/sys/class/gpio/16" on Pi3 with raspbian OS version 4.1.20+.

Comment: Ah ok, forgot the syntax or maybe it's different on the older Pis (I don't have a Pi2 or 3). Changed it to reflect OP's version.

Comment: Internally it's not "calling shell commands", it's writing to the kernel devices directly. It's only similar to what you're describing.

Comment: Yeah, it was the `echo` in terminal I called shell commands. I could've been clearer on that and, quite frankly, I don't know the internals that well; I just know that `pi-gpio` is writing to the the GPIO device via the same route and it's a good way of checking if OP can even *use* GPIOs without node.js... Should I correct/change something in my answer?

Comment: The pi-gpio module depends on the old command "gpio-admin" which accesses /sys/devices/virtual/gpio/gpioXX, that seems to make the problem. The "open" and "close" functions on the pi-gpio.js shoud be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Let's use 'rpio' module instead of 'pi-gpio'.

https://github.com/jperkin/node-rpio

It works fine on Pi3, zero etc.