# Nodejs pi-gpio not working on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi3

I'm just trying to turn on a simple led with pi-gpio on a Raspberry pi 3 model b. The problem is that when I start the program, I receive a error like this:

```
root@raspberrypi:/node# node app.js
Error when trying to open pin 16
gpio-admin: could not flush data to /sys/class/gpio/export: Device or resource busy

/node/app.js:4
if(err) throw err;
              ^
  Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c gpio-admin export 23 
  gpio-admin: could not flush data to /sys/class/gpio/export: Device or resource busy

  at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
  at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1183:11)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
  at Pipe.close (net.js:485:12)
  root@raspberrypi:/node#
```

This is my app.js

```
var gpio = require("pi-gpio");

gpio.open(16,"output",function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    gpio.write(16, true, function(err){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log("ouput on pin 16 ok");
    });

});
```

I've tried to install other module like rpi-gpio but nothing changed.

Comment: Roberto, this isn't an answer, but I've been working on a node library to access gpio via pigpio.  It's here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-pigpio, it's still a work in progress and currently only supports setPwmDutycycle and setServoPulsewidth.  On top I'm also building a node version of gpiozero: https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-gpiozero.  The current version uses wiring-pi, I working on converting it to pigpio.  I'm adding new features to both almost daily, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: But this looks like the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735925/gpio-over-raspberry-pi-3-model-b-using-node-js?rq=1